# Wine 8 has started crashing when trying to run yabridge - failed to create wineusb driver

Tags: 18.04, wine

I'm using Wine 8.0 to run some Windows VSTs in Ardour.  It has been working just fine using yabridge.  Today when I tried to start Ardour, wine crashed:

```
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] Initializing yabridge version 4.0.2
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] library:       '/home/xxxxx/.local/share/yabridge/libyabridge-vst3.so'
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] host:          '/home/xxxxx/.local/share/yabridge/yabridge-host.exe'
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] plugin:        '/home/xxxxx/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Common Files/VST3/LABS (64 Bit).vst3'
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] plugin type:   'VST3'
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] realtime:      'yes'
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] sockets:       '/run/user/1000/yabridge-LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq'
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] wine prefix:   '/home/xxxxx/.wine'
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] wine version:  '8.0'
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] 
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] config from:   '<defaults>'
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] hosting mode:  'individually, 64-bit'
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] other options: '<none>'
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] 
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] Enabled features:
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] - bitbridge support
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] - VST3 support
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] 
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] [Wine STDERR] 007c:err:wineusb:DriverEntry Failed to initialize Unix library, status 0xc0000135.
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] [Wine STDERR] 007c:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000135
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] [Wine STDERR] 003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 126
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] [Wine STDERR] 00a4:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] [Wine STDERR] 00a4:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] [Wine STDERR] 00a4:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
11:17:30 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] [Wine STDERR] 00a4:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
11:17:31 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] [Wine STDERR] 0120:err:virtual:virtual_setup_exception stack overflow 528 bytes addr 0x170059050 stack 0x20df0 (0x20000-0x21000-0x120000)
11:17:31 [LABS (64 Bit)-09AGLXaq] The Wine host process has exited unexpectedly. Check the output above for more information.
terminate called without an active exception
```

I've got wine 8.0 stable:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep wine

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

wine-stable/bionic,now 8.0.0.0~bionic-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
wine-stable-amd64/bionic,now 8.0.0.0~bionic-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
wine-stable-i386/bionic,now 8.0.0.0~bionic-1 i386 [installed,automatic]
winehq-stable/bionic,now 8.0.0.0~bionic-1 amd64 [installed]
```

I tried removing and reinstalling winehq-stable, but exactly the same thing is happening.  I haven't purged wine, as there are many gigabytes of virtual instruments installed and configured in `~/.wine` and I don't want to lose them.

Also tried wine staging with a similar result:

```
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 002c:fixme:winediag:LdrInitializeThunk wine-staging 8.2 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 002c:fixme:winediag:LdrInitializeThunk Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 0058:err:winedevice:ServiceMain Failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\win32k.sys"
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 0058:err:winedevice:ServiceMain Failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\dxgkrnl.sys"
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 0058:err:winedevice:ServiceMain Failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\dxgmms1.sys"
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 0080:err:winedevice:ServiceMain Failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\win32k.sys"
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 0080:err:winedevice:ServiceMain Failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\dxgkrnl.sys"
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 0080:err:winedevice:ServiceMain Failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\dxgmms1.sys"
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 007c:err:wineusb:DriverEntry Failed to initialize Unix library, status 0xc0000135.
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 007c:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000135
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 126
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 00a0:err:winedevice:ServiceMain Failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\win32k.sys"
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 00a0:err:winedevice:ServiceMain Failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\dxgkrnl.sys"
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 00a0:err:winedevice:ServiceMain Failed to load L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\dxgmms1.sys"
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 00a4:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 00a4:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 00a4:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 00a4:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 0074:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0000000000010026, 0): stub
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 0074:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010020, 0000000000010026): stub
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 002c:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (000000000001005E, 1): stub
12:20:04 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 002c:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (000000000001005C, 000000000001005E): stub
12:20:17 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] wine: configuration in L"/home/rowan/.wine" has been updated.
12:20:18 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] [Wine STDERR] 0154:err:virtual:virtual_setup_exception stack overflow 528 bytes addr 0x17005af00 stack 0x20df0 (0x20000-0x21000-0x120000)
12:20:18 [LABS (64 Bit)-0HIQbgik] The Wine host process has exited unexpectedly. Check the output above for more information.
terminate called without an active exception
```

The only thing I can remember doing recently that may have caused this is `sudo apt-get autoremove` to free up some disk space (there were a lot of packages removed).  Maybe something got nuked that wine needed?  The Wine wiki isn't helping, and I can't find anything that looks relevant by searching.  Any help on where to look next would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out yabridge is very fussy about which version of wine it runs under.  I downgraded wine to 7.0.0.0 and now it works.  I must have carelessly done `apt upgrade` at some point.

To downgrade wine, first `apt remove` the existing version.  Then `apt-cache madison winehq-stable` (or `winehq-staging` as appropriate) lists available versions.  Finally install the required version - note you have to manually install all four packages rather than just the virtual package otherwise you'll get a mix of versions.  For example:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable=7.0.0.0~bionic-1 wine-stable=7.0.0.0~bionic-1 wine-stable-amd64=7.0.0.0~bionic-1 wine-stable-i386:i386=7.0.0.0~bionic-1
```

Lastly, you can mark a package so that it isn't upgraded if you do `apt upgrade` by:

```
sudo apt-mark hold winehq-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

I use wine inside Bottle. I've similar setup. Ardour, LABS, Kontakt, yabridge.
I've still have Fixme STDERR. But everything works. I'm writing this because if someone want to run VSTs, there is a way to not to mess with default wine.
I use Default wine to play games.